# Grep multiple substrings from a variable without a loop

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I am writing a script that will parse a web interface of a UPS (Uninterruptable Power Supply)  for data, given the argument provided. I have my entire script coded correctly to accommodate for one argument.

What I would like to accomplish is entering one string of arguments separated by '+' signs, such as hostname+model+status+uptime, and then grep each one, without using a loop. Is this feasible?

The argument is assigned to $_var by use of the positional parameter $1. Like I said, I have this set up to work properly with one argument. I am only looking to modify the script for multiple arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl=/usr/bin/curl
grep=/bin/grep
sed=/bin/sed
site=<ommitted>

if [ ${#} -lt 1 ]
then
     echo "usage: $0 <vars := name|\"name|name\">"
     exit 1
fi

# required parameters
_vars=${1}

result="$(${curl} -s ${site} | ${sed} -e 's/1,142d//; s/<[^>]*>//g' | ${grep} -w -i -E ${_vars} | ${sed} 's/.*: //; s/^\([0-9.-]\+\) .*/\1/')"

echo "${result}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `+` to `|` and use `grep -E`:

```
vars='hostname+model+status+uptime'
... | grep -E "${vars//+/|}"
```

Comment: Yes, that solved it for me. Disregard the previous notifications. Thanks a bunch! I appreciate it.

Comment: Congratulations! You've just crossed the 200,000 mark :)

Comment: Thanks @kums: yes indeed this question nailed it.